# How do I prevent Router Advertisement from updating my IPv6 route?

Tags: router, linux-networking, ipv6

I want to send large IPv6 packets without fragmentation in RHEL6.5. I am using this command to test:

```
ping6 dest_ip -s 8952 -M do -c 100
```

This is what I have tried:

1. Set MTU:

   ```
   ifconfig eth0 mtu 9000
   ```
2. Delete the preconfiged IPv6 route:

   ```
   [root@myhost~]# ip -6 route|grep fc00
   fc00:10:24:86::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  expires 0sec mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
   [root@myhost~]# ip -6 route del fc00:10:24:86::/64
   ```
3. Add a new IPv6 route:

   ```
   [root@myhost~]# ip -6 route add fc00:10:24:86::/64 dev eth0 mtu 9000 metric 256
   [root@myhost~]# ip -6 route|grep eth0
   fc00:10:24:86::/64 dev eth0  metric 255  mtu 9000 advmss 8940 hoplimit 4294967295
   fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
   default via fe80::fefb:fbff:fe31:c280 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 1024  expires 0sec mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 64
   ```
4. After the above configs, run the ping command `ping6 dst_v6_ip -s 8952 -M do -c 100`. I can see the first of the 100 packets are delivered successfully but after a while it shows `Message too long`.
5. Then I check the existing IPv6 route, found it is changed by RA(I suppose)

   ```
   [root@myhost~]# ip -6 route|grep fc00
   fc00:10:24:86::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  expires 0sec mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
   ```
6. I have tried to disable RA and autoconf by using the following commands:

   ```
   sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf=0
   sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra=0
   ```

But it still doesn't work.

How can I prevent the RA/AUCONF from replacing my manually-configured IPv6 route?

Comment: This isn't RA. It's coming from the kernel. Which means you need to set the MTU in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`.

Comment: Could this be being set via Path MTU Discovery, which is a core part of IPv6? Perhaps as the path farther down the line changes to a link with a smaller MTU? Look for ICMPv6 Packet Too Big messages coming back at you.